# API ссылка перестает работать после добавление переменых в нее

Tags: php

Есть API ссылка и в ней надо в определенном месте вставить переменые. Простым языком к `string` добавить переменую.

Если в строке прописать руками на месте переменых даты начало - "2018-12-28" и дата конец - "2019-03-30" то все работает, а если через переменые формировать строку то дальше код не работает. Хотя вывести переменую `$create_json` и посмотрев на нее то все в порядке.

У кого есть идеи почему не работает так ?

```
$today = date("Y-m-d");
$pastdate = date("Y-m-d", mktime(0, 0, 0, date('m'), date('d') - 92, date('Y')));

echo '<p>'.$today.'</p>';
echo '<p>'.$pastdate.'</p>';

$create_json = "http://api.spending.gov.ua/api/v2/api/transactions/?payers_edrpous=04053743&payers_edrpous=02143413&payers_edrpous=05517771&payers_edrpous=03344510&payers_edrpous=40169379&payers_edrpous=25436247&payers_edrpous=03192980&startdate={$pastdate}&enddate={$today}";

$json = file_get_contents($create_json);
$obj = json_decode($json); ?>

<table>
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Платник (код)</th>
        <th>Одержувач (код)</th>
        <th>Призначення платежу</th>
        <th>Дата</th>
        <th>Сума</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <?php foreach ($obj as $itemline) {
        if ($itemline->amount_cop < 50000) { ?>
            <tr>
                <td style="    width: 20%;">
                    <?php echo $itemline->payer_name; ?>
                </td>
                <td style="    width: 20%;">
                    <?php echo $itemline->recipt_name; ?>
                </td>
                <td style="    width: 25%;">
                    <?php echo $itemline->payment_details; ?>
                </td>
                <td style="    width: 15%;">
                    <?php echo $itemline->trans_date; ?>
                </td>
                <td style="    width: 20%;">
                    <?php echo $itemline->amount_cop . " " . $itemline->currency; ?>
                </td>

            </tr>
        <?php } ?>
    <?php } ?>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Введите получившеюся ссылку в строку браузера и поймете в чем проблема)

Comment: @Yura Rosiak  Спасибо, я даже не подумал глянуть туда. Попросили отнять 92 дня, отнял :(

Comment: На дворе -62 марта 2019